# Why does Wix session.Message for FileInUse shows up empty?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a Wix Custom Action that looks for Outlook and prompts the user to kill it. I don't want to kill OL myself but, want the user to do it.
Here's my Custom Action:

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult PromptToCloseOutlook(Session session)
    {
        session.Log("Detecting running instances of Microsoft Outlook...");
        ActionResult retVal = ActionResult.Success;

        Process outlook;
        while (null != (outlook = Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook").FirstOrDefault()))
        {
            session.Log("Microsoft Outlook is running.");

            var result = session.Message(
                // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371614(v=vs.85).aspx
                InstallMessage.FilesInUse,
                new Record(null, "outlook.exe", outlook.Id)
            );


            session.Log("User selected option:" + result);

            if (result == MessageResult.Cancel)
            {
                session.Log("User does not wish to close Outlook at this time.");
                retVal = ActionResult.UserExit;
            }
            else if (result == MessageResult.Ignore)
            {
                session.Log("User wished to ignore and proceed.");
                break;
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

I invoke this as:

```
<Custom Action="CA.PromptToCloseOutlook" Before="InstallValidate" />
```

However, when it runs on Win7, it shows a blank window (but correctly waits till OL is closed)
[image: empty window]

On WinXP, the loop runs for ever, saying the PID is invalid. Since, I use the PID from the running instance, I'm not sure how that's possible.

Any ideas what's wrong with the code?